# Which is better: Using inbuilt Protractor/selenium functionalities OR Installing other node packages for protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, npm, protractor

This is a general question for all the npm packages available for Protractor.

One example is `linkuisref-locator` package:

```
 <a ui-sref="home" class="ng-scope" href="/home">Home</a>
```

To select the above element, there are two approaches:
1) `by.css()` OR `by.xpath()` -- These are the ones already included in Protractor
2) `by.linkUiSref()` -- This requires to install another package([protractor-linkuisref-locator](https://www.npmjs.org/package/protractor-linkuisref-locator))

The second one is undoubtedly more readable and closer to angular components. However, I am not sure if this is a good approach for testing keeping in mind the performance and other things!

I am open for any inputs/discussions/suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my insight.

I've personally done testing using `protractor` in a few projects and I haven't ever needed nothing beyond than what `protractor` offers - basically, you can find anything using `by.css` or `by.xpath`.

Additionally, if you look at the [`by.linkUiSref` implementation](https://github.com/crzrcn/protractor-linkuisref-locator/blob/master/index.js), you would see that it is rather simple and is based on the attribute-checking `CSS selector`:

- `a[ui-sref="value"]`
- `a[data-ui-sref="value"]`

Which leads to the point: is

```
by.linkUiSref("value")
```

much more readable than

```
by.css('a[ui-sref="value"]')
```

<sup>Well, strictly speaking, since there can be also `data-ui-sref` attributes, the css selector would be `a[ui-sref="value"],a[data-ui-sref="value"]` which is still - a simple one.</sup>

---

On the other side and for the analogy example, I'm heavily relying on [`jasmine-matchers`](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers) for additional `jasmine` expectations, like `expect(array).toBeArrayOfObjects();` or `expect(date).toBeDate();`, which are basically, in a way, similar shortcuts that can be written manually. Though, most of the new expectation functions are not trivial, solve common day-to-day assertion problems while testing and improve readability.

In this case, I can see the clear point of using an another third-party extension package.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your insight Alecxe. This is helpful and I get a feeling that its better to use protractor in-built functionalities. I will wait for more answers(if any). Else, this one is good enough to be marked as Answered

Comment: @SakshiSingla you are welcome, this is a really interesting problem to think about, thank you. I've also added some notes about `jasmine-matchers` - hope I haven't made things more complicated. I guess, in short, I would say here "depends on the implementation complexity and the time you can possibly save" - if it really saves you time and solves the non-trivial problem that is already solved - then it make sense to reuse. Otherwise, like in this case, I think there is no point, too easy to do it with the built-in functionality.

Comment: Alecxe, this marks the answer complete :) Thanks for the inputs. Please keep sharing in case you have any more suggestions/inputs on the same.